# Print Right aligned # stair case using single for loop

Tags: c

I want to print a Right Aligned # Staircase with **single loop.**

I was trying to print a Right aligned # staircase.
I did it.
But I want to print the same with **single loop.**

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(i+j>=n-1)
        {
          printf("#");
        }
        else
        {
          printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `printf("%*c", n - i, '#');`

Comment: Replace one of the loops by `goto`.

Comment: Suggest spending the time to read [printf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) -- well worth the time it takes (and it will save you untold amounts of time going forward). Follow it up with [scanf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (ditto)

Comment: You'll find the shape your code produces described as a pyramid in other questions, and often there'll be mention of Mario.  The solution suggested by @Kamil Cuk would produce a slanting line of `#` marks, but doesn't fill in the area underneath, unlike your 2-loop code.  You could adapt it, though, up to a given fixed size, with `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%*.*s\n", n, i+1, "##########");` which works as long as `n` is no longer than the string of `#` marks.  There are ways around that if need be.

Comment: That really Works.Can you Explain the Printf format of your code @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: there are a lot of ways to do this. Here are a few off the top of my head.

Recursion:

```
void print(int n, int j) {
    if (j < n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            putchar(i + j >= n - 1 ? '#' : ' ');
        }

        puts("");
        print(n, j + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    print(10, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

`memset`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, n = 10;
    char s[n+1];
    memset(s, ' ', sizeof(char) * (n + 1));

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        memset(s + n - i, '#', sizeof(char) * (n + 1 - i));
        s[n+1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Loop to `n * n` and use a conditional to determine when to print a new line:

```
int main() {
    int i, j, n = 10;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i <= n * n; i++) {
        putchar(j++ >= n - 1 ? '#' : ' ');

        if (i % n == 0) {
            puts("");
            j = i / n;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`goto`:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0, j, n = 10;

    loop:
    for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
        putchar(j++ >= n - 1 ? '#' : ' ');
    }

    puts("");
    if (i++ < n) goto loop;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does these programs reduce the Time Complexity and Space Complexity?

Comment: No. The time complexity for printing a staircase is the same as yours, which is already optimal: O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the string of `#` marks is long enough (at least `n` of them), you can use:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%*.*s\n", n, i+1, "##########");
```

The `*` markers in the format string mean 'read an `int` from the parameter list' — see the POSIX specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), for example, or the C11 specification of [`fprintf()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1).  The notation `"%10.6s\n"`, for example, would mean "print a field 10 characters wide, right justified, blank filled on the left, with no more than 6 characters coming from the string argument".  So, if `n` is `10`, the loop works as:

```
printf("%10.1s\n", "##########");    // 9 blanks, 1 hash
printf("%10.2s\n", "##########");    // 8 blanks, 2 hashes
…
printf("%10.9s\n", "##########");    // 1 blank, 9 hashes
printf("%10.10s\n", "##########");   // 0 blanks, 10 hashes
```

You can try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%*.*s\n", n, i + 1, "##########");

    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 10;
    char data[n + 1];
    memset(data, '#', n);
    data[n] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%*.*s\n", n, i + 1, data);

    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 10;
    char *data = malloc(n + 1);
    memset(data, '#', n);
    data[n] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%*.*s\n", n, i + 1, data);

    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

The latter two will handle values of `n` larger than `10` without any problem. As shown, the first won't (but it can be adapted to handle moderate values of `n` fairly easily, of course).  Note that the middle one uses a VLA (variable length array); that's a mandatory feature of C99 and an optional feature of C11 and C18.  The last one should check that `malloc()` succeeds. For plausible values of `n`, it is unlikely to fail in this context, but in a bigger program, the check is always advisable.